# android Navigation view is not working fine for 4.2.1 jelly bean

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-navigationview

android navigation view is not working fine when language is arabic. This issue is only happened on 4.2.1 jelly bean. there is a alignment issue of icons.please take a look on screen shot
[image]

Comment: What is the issue please share more details, are you using custom list item ?

Comment: see the alignment of icons . all the icons should be on right side

Comment: post your xml file, if you are using custom list item , if you are using relative layout change it to linear layout this flip happens with Arabic using relative layout.

Comment: i am using navigation view and iam getting all the items from menu folder

Comment: i am not using custom view or listview

Comment: great ! and you should put android:supportsRtl="true" in your application tag and force supporting right to left in you activity for jelly bean @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
private void forceRTLIfSupported()
{
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
        getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    }
}

Comment: @ArslanWaheed, take a look at this url: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/ and if you are menu, as the bottom view of your navigation drawer, use menu.xml, you can easily put your icons on left/right and text on the other end.

PS: Please include more information (codes, layout designs etc) rather than just a screenshot. And take a look at this url as well. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i already did this solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put android:supportsRtl="true" inside your application tag and force supporting right to left in you activity for jelly bean in you activities like this :

```
         @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) 
private void forceRTLIfSupported() { 
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){      getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DI‌​RECTION_RTL); 
} 
}
```